# How can I build a feature branch out of a subset of TeamCity projects?

Tags: git, teamcity

In a teamcity setup with 8 projects, I would like to build all projects that have a particular 'feature' branch on them and have the remainder build default-master.

Is there a better way then having a single trigger project with the feature as a property, and cloning/building each? The idea is that each project will have an artifact that gets deployed at the very end.